# Regular Expression for Particular String

Tags: java, regex

How to write regular expression for the char `{` ?

I need to write a pattern for the string  `{\"2\":{\"0\":abc}}...`

When i exclude `{` from the string its working fine

All comments are appreciated

Comment: Generating a regex to match a given string is very hard, considering that there are an infinite number of possible regexes.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to match/find?

Comment: First thing that came to my mind: Escape it. Just like in [Kendall Frey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/785745/kendall-frey) answer. But I guess you would have figured this out yourself. Maybe you should improve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `{` character in a regex, you need to escape it like this: `\{`.

Answer (score 0):

The flower brackets in regex has special function. For example, if you mention \d{3,5} --it denotes capture any digits of length minimum 3 to a max 5. since it has a special function in regex it needs to be escaped.